# Как тестировать верстку под Ipad Pro - без Xcode?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая страничка:
http://webmaster.ayrveda.ru/ecoline-windows-test-task/
Пытаюсь разобраться, как верстать под Ipad Pro.
В фаербаге в эмуляторе мазиллы - вроде бы все нормально выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в эмуляторе Google Chrome все печально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Почему это происходит и какому эмулятору больше верить можно?
(как отображение данной страницы будет выглядеть в реальной жизни?)
Какой подход применять в данном случае для решения проблемы?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128846/discussion-on-question-by-mike-kharkov-----ipad-pro-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте сервисы наподобие Browerstack или Saucelabs.

Если же хочется быть независимым от сторонних сервисов - можно взять любой более-менее современный Мак(ну или собрать Хакинтош), да тестировать через эмуляцию в XCode(прикрутив, допустим Selenium и завернув это все в CI).

Ну а если не хочется технических заморочек и есть ресурсы - проще купить набор наиболее популярных на рынке устройств, для "живого тестирования". Причем это касается не только устройств Apple, но и устройств на Android(особенно от Samsung, с их любовью к "быть не как все").

"Device Mode" из "Chrome Dev Tools" умеет только подменять параметры(размер, dpi) Viewport-а, изменять медиум(дисплей/печать/голосовой помощник),заголовок User-Agent, режимы курсора - для полноценного тестирования верстки на других устройствах и в других браузерах этого явно не достаточно..